# Creating a text file with a variable as the name of the text file

Tags: python, file, variables

I need to create a text file that stores the answers a user gives to a set of questions they are asked. This file needs to have a unique case number as its file name. The code below does that apart from the file isn't a text file, its file type just says "file".

The file **needs** to have the contents of the rnumber file as its file name. That is really important.

Does anyone know how this could be done?

```
def casenumberallocator(filename, answers, typeofdevice):
    os.chdir("H:\V4 Program\Questions")
    availablecasenumber = "not found"
    while availablecasenumber == "not found":
        rnumber = random.randint(1, 100)
        if rnumber in randomnumberlog:
            one = 1
        else:
            availablecasenumber = "found"
            randomnumberlog.append(rnumber)
    case = dict()
    case[rnumber] = {"Case number": rnumber,
               "Device": typeofdevice,
               filename: answers}
    casestring = ''.join('{}{}'.format(key, val) for key, val in case[rnumber].items())
    os.chdir("H:\V4 Program\Case_files")
    with open(str(rnumber), "w") as file: 
    #I have also tried str(rnumber).txt, and str(rnumber)".txt" but neither works. 
        file.write(casestring)
    os.chdir("H:\V4 Program")
```

Comment: Why don't you use `str.format` again? `str(rnumber).txt` would just be an attribute error, as it attempts to access an attribute strings clearly do not have. Also it doesn't matter what the file extension is except as far as it associates the file with a specific default program; just Open With a text editor and take a look.

Comment: Please don't always do this superfluous `chdir`. If you want to open a file in a different folder just prepend the filename with the folder in the call to `open`.

Answer (score 0):

You must "concatenate"...

```
open('"'+str(rnumber)+'.txt"', "w")
```

... I think...

Comment: No need for those extra quote marks, unless you want the filename itself to include quote marks.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Stefano, a slightly edited version of your answer worked.

```
open(str(rnumber)+'.txt'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use string interpolation, which automatically converts the value to a string before inserting it.

```
"{}.txt".format(rnumber)
```

Or

```
"{}.{}".format(rnumber, "txt")
```